# How to create a dropdown list with progress bar inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does anyone have any idea how to show a progress bar in dropdown/select list?

For progress bar I'm using jQuery's progress bar:
http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

I've tried search available plugs, but they only attach image, like ddSlick
http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick
But those kind of plug-ins only attaches static images

What I'm trying to do is a dropdown list that lists out 10 people, and beside their names there should be a progress bar showing their work load

Thanks alot!

edit: add html

```
                      <select class="taskAssignUser" name="taskAssignUser">
                         <option value="">Select Member</option>
                        <c:forEach items="${getMemberList}" var="v">
                        <option value="${v.userId}" ${v.userId == u.taskAssignUser? 'selected':'' }>${v.username}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                      </select>
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate how your HTML is, or will be, structured? That way we can provide help, otherwise the question will be closed as off-topic (we don't recommend tools, books or other '[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)').

Comment: ok i've added html, but it's a simple select as I have no idea how do show the progress bar in select box

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a real progress bar plugin for that, because there will be no real-time change in the graphic.

What you can do instead is pre-generate progress bar graphics (JPEG/PNG/...) and show the appropriate one per person instead. You'd only need to generate, say, 20 different ones, each accounting for a 5% progress block, unless you really need the higher granularity.

So then you can use these static images with ddSlick or whichever graphical dropdown you want to use.

Comment: thanks for the opinion i've thought but this, but my progress isn't shown in percentage, it's like x/28800 (total number of minutes per 20 working days), so that means I would need to create alot of images

Comment: If you need to show it in a dropdownlist, that automatically limits the size of the image, does it not? So if you would have a maximum width of 100 pixels for the image, would you need to generate more than 100 images?

Comment: thanks Roy! I think you do have a point here, might not need to show the exact detail! I guess this will be something that I can do, let me think about it